# How to autostart KDM on boot in OpenBSD 6.0?

Tags: kde, startup, openbsd, rc, kdm

I have installed kde4 (via running `# pkg_add kde4`) on my OpenBSD 6.0 VM and I would like to automatically boot KDM on startup. I have followed [the most applicable guide](http://openbsdsupport.org/KDM.html) Google found me, but it didn't work. Specifically adding:

```
kdm_flags=""

if [ "X${kdm_flags}" != X"NO" ]; then
   /usr/local/bin/kdm ${kdm_flags} ;
   echo -n 'kdm '
fi
```

to my `/etc/rc.conf` **does not** cause KDM to start on boot for me. Any ideas? My full `/etc/rc.conf` (which besides the above modification I have not changed since I installed OpenBSD) file can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/1137e5ed5a88d811e616e7551440c431). If it is relevant running `startkde4` starts KDE without a problem. `/usr/local/bin/kdm` does exist.

Comment: What does the system do on boot? Does it boot to the console, or something else?

Comment: Boots to console.

Comment: Did you pick the "enable X11" thing during the install? http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq11.html#ConfigX

Comment: Can't recall, although if I didn't wouldn't I be unable to start KDE at all? As I have been able to with the `startkde4` command.

Comment: My present machdep.allowaperture value in /etc/sysctl.conf is non-zero if that indicates that I did choose an X server.

Comment: Why did I get a downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave `/etc/rc.conf` as is. It even has a prominent header saying `DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE!!`, twice. Instead, modify `/etc/rc.conf.local`. *But you don't need to do even that*:

Tested on OpenBSD 6.1-stable (amd64) running in a VirtualBox VM (this installs `kde4-4.14.3` and enables KDM):

```
$ doas pkg_add kde4
$ doas rcctl enable kdm
$ doas reboot
```

KDM will start upon reboot. KDM will start the KDE desktop environment when you log in.

You may also start KDM through `doas rcctl start kdm` without rebooting.

If you already have [`xenodm(1)`](http://man.openbsd.org/xenodm) (previously known as `xdm`) running, stop it and disable it first, before starting KDM:

```
$ doas rcctl stop xenodm
$ doas rcctl disable xenodm
$ doas rcctl enable kdm
```

See also [`rcctl(8)`](http://man.openbsd.org/rcctl).

---

Regarding `/etc/doas.conf` (from comments):

This is my `/etc/doas.conf` on my OpenBSD 6.1-stable system:

```
permit nopass keepenv root as root
permit persist :trusted
```

It allows root to use `doas` without password and without resetting the environment (this line is taken straight out of [`doas.conf(5)`](http://man.openbsd.org/doas.conf)), and it allows members of the group `trusted` (a special group on my system) to use `doas` with password.

To grant usage of `doas` to a single user `myuser`, I'd probably use something like

```
permit persist myuser
```

as a bare minimum, or

```
permit setenv { -ENV PS1=$DOAS_PS1 SSH_AUTH_SOCK } :wheel
```

as suggested by `doas.conf(5)` (and then add the user to the `wheel` group).

The `persist` option allows for passwordless `doas` invocations during five minutes after a successful `doas` invocation has been done. This option was added in OpenBSD 6.1.

Comment: My `/etc/doas.conf` file is empty. Is there a way to automatically create a basic conf file without knowing its format? I saw the man page http://man.openbsd.org/doas.conf.5 but honestly it's not that helpful. I created the file with no contents (in case it just needs to exist, regardless of contents) and running `doas pkg_add kde4` returns: `doas: Operation not permitted`.

Comment: @BrentonHorne See updated answer.

Comment: This is odd now (with your doas.conf file) `doas pkg_add kde4` is returning: `doas: syntax error at line 2` and `doas: syntax error at line 3`.

Comment: @BrentonHorne Ah, you're still on OpenBSD 6.0? Skip the `persist` option then.

Comment: Followed the upgrade guide so I thought it was 6.1, but it could still be at 6.0.

Comment: @BrentonHorne If you have issues using `doas` and you just want to get KDM working, just `su -` and run the commands without `doas`. Then get back to configuring `doas` when you're done. Ask a new question about `doas` here if you have further issues getting it to work.

Comment: I was running this as root, so not used to OpenBSD I didn't know doas was akin to a replacement for sudo.

Comment: @BrentonHorne Ah, that too. Yes, `doas` is a replacement for `sudo`. The OpenBSD developers wanted a minimal utility that was easier to configure correctly. It was introduced in OpenBSD 5.8.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can check under OpenBSD specific KDE readme files under:

```
/usr/local/share/doc/pkg-readmes/
```

you can find more about KDE OpenBSD related

Comment: Also please not you should put files under rc.local for that rather than rc.conf

Comment: https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq10.html#rc